# How do I remove the auto scrolling from a grid?

Tags: html, scrollbar

I'm working on a grid in ASP.Net.
In chrome, the scroll bar didn't appear automatically,
so I added in the div of the grid:

```
overflow-x: scroll
```

Now, when I open the page in IE 10, I have 2 scroll-bars – 
one that I've defined, and the other automatically created…

How can I remove the auto scroll bar in IE?

Thanks,
Yael

Comment: You mean the scroll bar of the page or a scroll bar for the grid?
Can you post some code?

Answer (score 0):

**`overflow: auto (or overflow-y: auto) is the correct way to go.`**

Comment: I changed the code in the div as you suggested:
`div style="overflow: auto;"`
but I still have the same problem